# How can i set the Property strictFileInteractability

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

geckodriver 0.24.0 introduces the capability strictFileInteractability see below,
but I haven't found a possibility to set this capability.

Code trials:

```
FirefoxProfile profile=new FirefoxProfile();

// Has no effect
profile.setPreference("strictFileInteractability", true);
```

...

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();

// Has no effect
options.setCapability("strictFileInteractability", true);
```

...

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

// Has no effect
capabilities.setCapability("strictFileInteractability", true);
```

Did someone manage to successfully set this capability?

Changelog:
github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
w3c.github.io/webdriver/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*GeckoDriver v0.24.0* introduced us to `strictFileInteractability` capability.

As per the **Capabilities** section within [WebDriver W3C Living Document](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#capabilities):

```
Capability                  Key                         Value Type  Description
----------                  ---                         ----------  -----------
Strict file interactability "strictFileInteractability" boolean     Defines the current session’s strict file interactability.
```

---

As per the discussion [Add support for 'strictFileInteractability' W3C capability](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6721) `strictFileInteractability` capability was added from [[java] Adding a type-safe option for strictFileInteractability capability](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/031cedd270cace9fd74527e0885c7875a468131b) pull request.

---

### Example

- Using *Java*, `Option` Class and *Firefox*:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Utility/BrowserDrivers/geckodriver.exe");
    FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
    opt.setCapability("strictFileInteractability", true);
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(opt);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    driver.quit();
    ```
  - Console Output:

    ```
    Google
    ```
- Using *Java*, `DesiredCapabilities` Class and *Firefox*:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Utility/BrowserDrivers/geckodriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
    dc.setCapability("strictFileInteractability", true);
    FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
    opt.merge(dc);
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(opt);
    driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
    System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
    driver.quit();
    ```
  - Console Output:

    ```
    Page Title is : Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers
    ```